# resolve in catch block is not definied

Tags: javascript, promise

Why can't I call resolve in the catch block ?

Wanted catch a failed request and try it again in the catch block but 
I'm getting resolve is not defined. I'm inside of the promise why cant I call resolve

```
module.exports.makeRequest = function(ID,requestAttempts) {

return Promise()
  .then(function(val, resolve, reject){
      request.get(url, {json:true}, function(err, res) {
          if(err || res.body.error_code)
              reject(err || res.body)
          else
              resolve(res.body)
      })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      if (requestAttempts <= 0) reject(error);
        console.log("Error :",error, `\n Try to repead the request (attempts left: ${requestAttempts} )`); 
        resolve(makeRequest(ID,requestAttempts - 1)); //HERE
  });

}
```

Comment: No no no. You will want to read [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `Promise` constructor is incorrect, and your `resolve` function is not within the scope of the `.catch` function's callback.  Your `makeRequest` function is also not exposed in the local scope so it can't even call itself.

I would further suggest moving the "retry" logic outside of the core function that actually processes the AJAX request.

```
function makeOneRequest(ID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         request.get(url, {json: true}, (err, res) => {
             if (err || res.body.error_code) {
                 reject(err || res.body);
             } else {
                 resolve(res.body);
             }
         });
    });
}

function makeRequest(ID, count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        return Promise.reject();
    } else {
        return makeOneRequest(ID).catch(() => makeRequest(ID, count - 1);
    }
}

module.exports.makeRequest = makeRequest;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me and I also understood your points :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Promise` constructor takes a function with `resolve` and `reject`. `.then` does not. If you want to resolve out of a `.then` or a `.catch`, just return the value. If you want to reject out of a `.then` or a `.catch`, just throw an error.

I think you want something like this - just follow the structure - the logic might not be what you want.

```
function makeRequest(ID,requestAttempts) {
   return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       request.get(url, {json:true}, function(err, res) {
          if(err || res.body.error_code)
              reject(err || res.body)
          else
              resolve(res.body)
       })
    })
}

 makeRequest().catch(function (error) {
     if (requestAttempts <= 0) throw error;
        console.log("Error :",error, `\n Try to repead the request (attempts 
        left: ${requestAttempts} )`); 
    return makeRequest(ID,requestAttempts - 1));
 });
```

Comment: @Alnitak i know theres problems with it - it needs reformulated by the OP - just trying to show the general pattern...